# How to realize pre-loading HTML "parts" in background for reuse when needed by components later?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have an embedded PDF viewer as a Svelte component (based on [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)) that requires quite some time (more than 1-2 seconds) to initialize before a user can use it or before a command to open a PDF file can be triggered.

The component itself is rather simple; it's basically only an iframe:

```
<div>
    {#if !pdfjsViewerAppRunning}
    <div>
        <div>Loading PDF viewer...</div>
        <progress />
    </div>
    {/if}
    <iframe src="external/pdf-viewer.html" title="PDF Viewer"
            bind:this={iframe} on:load={onWebViewerRunning}
    />
</div>
```

I'm embedding the component somewhat like this:

```
<div>
    {#if showPdf}
    <MyPdfViewer pdf={pdf} />
    {/if}
</div>
```

Now if `showPdf` toggles from true to false and back, the whole DOM tree of my component gets destroyed and recreated, including the underlying iframe and its content. This means that the PDF viewer will need to be reinitialize every time, resulting in 1-2 seconds of user time wasted every time. I want to avoid this waiting time, therefore have to prevent having the PDF viewer re-load/re-initialize for each toggling.

I had considered replacing the `{#if}` wrap by a visibility-toggling mechanism. My actual setup is however more complicated than this; there are more `{#if}` wrappers beyond the scope that the component gets embedded. So toggling the visibility could not be implemented without violating fundamental Svelte principles.

As an alternative, I'm considering to place the iframe somewhere "global", keep it hidden at first, and basically "move" it into the correct DOM node when the component actually needs it (and put it back when it's not needed anymore). I don't have to worry about having two instances of the component for now; it can be assumed that the application will only show only one PDF viewer at a time.

My questions are:

1. Is there another (better?) alternative to my idea to solve the waiting time challenge?
2. What are the best-practices to put a "long-loading" part of the DOM tree hidden in a "global" location and temporarily move it to another location when needed?

Comment: What causes the delay? If it is network there are ways to [preload data using `<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload).

Comment: `pdf.js` is a pretty complex library that renders PDF files natively in the browser. It's 100% written in JavaScript - and is therefore unfortunately just very slow to load. The code itself is already compressed, so preloading the files would not have as much of an impact. The actual initialization time (i.e. interpreting & running JavaScript code) is the culprit.